# SQL Update or insert query not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've spent around 2 hours now changing the script and finding other ways of doing it but no luck. If anyone could please point out any issues in my script that would be great. Many thanks.

I've updated the script, hopefully this gives a better understanding and more detail.

```
<?php

    session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["user"]) or !is_array($_SESSION["user"]) or empty($_SESSION["user"])) {
      // redirect to login page
}
$dbhost   = "localhost";
$dbname   = "**";
$dbuser   = "root";
$dbpass   = "**";

// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
// new data



error_reporting(E_ALL);

                    $work = $_POST['work'];
                    $education = $_POST['education'];
                    $location = $_POST['location'];
                    $relationship = $_POST['relationship'];
                    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
                    $email = $_POST['email'];
                    $website = $_POST['website'];
                    $language = $_POST['language'];
                    $skill = $_POST['skill'];
                    $tumblr = $_POST['tumblr'];
                    $instagram = $_POST['instagram'];
                    $skype = $_POST['skype'];
                    $facebook = $_POST['facebook'];
                    $youtube = $_POST['youtube'];
                    $twitter = $_POST['twitter'];
                    $about = $_POST['about'];
                    $user_id = $_SESSION['user']['id'];

                    echo $work."</br>";
                    echo $education."</br>";
                    echo $location."</br>";
                    echo $relationship."</br>";
                    echo $phone."</br>";
                    echo $email."</br>";
                    echo $website."</br>";
                    echo $language."</br>";
                    echo $skill."</br>";
                    echo $tumblr."</br>";
                    echo $instagram."</br>";
                    echo $skype."</br>";
                    echo $facebook."</br>";
                    echo $youtube."</br>";
                    echo $twitter."</br>";
                    echo $about."</br>";
                    echo $user_id;

/*
        "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1=’SomeValue’)
    UPDATE Table1 SET (…) WHERE Column1=’SomeValue’
ELSE
    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (…)"
*/

$sql = "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']['id'].")
    UPDATE user_details SET 
    (work='".$work."',education='".$education."',location='".$location."',relationship='".$relationship."',phone='".$phone."',email='".$email."',website='".$website."',language='".$language."',skill='".$skill."',tumblr='".$tumblr."',instagram='".$instagram."',skype='".$skype."',facebook='".$facebook."',youtube='".$youtube."',twitter='".$twitter."',about='".$about."') 
WHERE user_id='".$user_id."'
ELSE INSERT INTO user_details (work,education,location,relationship,phone,email,website,language,skill,tumblr,instagram,skype,facebook,youtube,twitter,about,user_id)
VALUES
('".$work."','".$education."','".$location."','".$relationship."','".$phone."','".$email."','".$website."','".$language."','".$skill."','".$tumblr."','".$instagram."','".$skype."','".$facebook."','".$youtube."','".$twitter."','".$about."','".$user_id."')";
                    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
                    $q->execute();
        var_dump(mysql_error())



// header('Location: ../usr_settings.php');


?>
```

Answer (score 2):

More details pls. Error message for example should be useful. In UPDATE you have $$email (doulbe $$ sign) which probably tries to enter empty email. If it cannot be empty - query may crash.

Comment: Well theres no error message. All fields are being filled and posted from form as I checked via echo method. No SQL errors or anything. 
I'm trying to update a database table, and if they isn't a query with a user ID I need to insert a new one.

Comment: And, of course, you are running that query with mysql_query or something similar?

Comment: Yep mysql not mysqli